# Unable to use SHAP GradientExplainer due to Tensorflow error (tensors are unhashable)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, vgg-net, shap

I have been stuck on this error for a long time and is there anyway to resolve it without downgrading my tensorflow version? All the solutions I have found till now have recommended using TF<2.0 which I don't want to do. Current TF version = 2.4.1, Keras version = 2.4.3, using google colab

I am trying to use SHAP GradientExplainer with the VGG 16 model to see how a particular layer impacts predictions.

The code is :

```
e = shap.GradientExplainer((model.layers[7].input, model.layers[-1].output), map2layer(preprocess_input(X.copy()), 7))
shap_values, indexes = e.shap_values(map2layer(to_predict, 7), ranked_outputs=2)
index_names = np.vectorize(lambda x: class_names[str(x)][1])(indexes)
index_names
```

The error is:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-b3a265bc3cde> in <module>()
----> 1 e = shap.GradientExplainer((model.layers[7].input, model.layers[-1].output), map2layer(preprocess_input(X.copy()), 7))
      2 shap_values, indexes = e.shap_values(map2layer(to_predict, 7), ranked_outputs=2)
      3 index_names = np.vectorize(lambda x: class_names[str(x)][1])(indexes)
      4 index_names


<ipython-input-11-f110beabf449> in map2layer(x, layer)
      1 def map2layer(x, layer):
----> 2     feed_dict = dict(zip([model.layers[0].input], [preprocess_input(x.copy())]))
      3     return K.get_session().run(model.layers[layer].input, feed_dict)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py in __hash__(self)
    259   def __hash__(self):
    260     raise TypeError('Tensors are unhashable. (%s)'
--> 261                     'Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.' % self)
    262 
    263   # Note: This enables the KerasTensor's overloaded "right" binary

TypeError: Tensors are unhashable. (KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_1'), name='input_1', description="created by layer 'input_1'"))Instead, use tensor.ref() as the key.
```

Comment: Can you show more of the stack trace?

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps it's easier to read if you past it in the main question

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're feeding in a `Tensor` or `KerasTensor` into your feed_dict. Python tries to hash the dictionary keys (a python dict is a hash-map), which raises the error you're seeing. The reason is that Tensors are not hashable (meaning that they don't have an implementation of the `__hash__` method).

To solve this, make sure that the feed_dict keys are placeholders or [`keras.Input`](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/input/) objects instead.

Comment: Sorry but this is the first time i'm using VGG or doing image processing, how would I check that the feed_dict keys are keras.Input objects and if they aren't how do I convert them to that type?

Comment: Just inspect the `feed_dict` object you're creating. Perhaps the solution is to follow the suggestion in the error message, i.e. to use the `tensor.ref()` as your key.

Comment: I personally haven't used tensorflow / keras in a while, so I might be wrong